# unable to instantiate class within method?

Tags: java, methods, instantiation

I am trying to instantiate an object from the following class:

```
public class Name {

    //The unmodified name
    private String name;

    //The modified name
    private String preprocessedName;

    /**
     * Constructor method which stores the original name in the name variable
     * @param inputName
     */
    public Name(String inputName){
        //Store the name
        this.name = inputName;

        //Initialise the preProcessedName
        this.preprocessedName = null;   
    }

    /**
     * Retrieves the original name
     * @return the original name
     */
    public String getName(){
        return this.name;
    }

    /**
     * Stores the preprocessed name in the preprocessedName variable
     * @param the preprocessed name
     */
    public void setPreprocessedName(String processedInput){
        this.preprocessedName = processedInput;
    }

    /**
     * Retrieves the preprocessed name
     * @return the preprocessed name
     */
    public String getpreprocessedName(){
        return this.preprocessedName;
    }
}
```

Within the following method:

```
/**
     * Private method which instantiates names as a name object. 
     * @param names
     */
    private void processInput(ArrayList<String> names){
        library = new ArrayList<Name>();
        for(String name : names){
            Name tempName = new Name("r");

            //Not bringing up any methods from the class
            **strong text**tempName.**strong text**



            //add to the library
            library.add(tempName);
        }
    }
```

I am unable to use any methods from the Name class when I create the object, do you know why this is happening? e.g. it does not bring up the getters and setters from the class when I try auto completion.

Comment: Forget about whether your IDE is bringing up getters and setters. What happens when you just write the code and try to compile it?

Comment: All seems good so just try to write it yourself like Kevin suggested. Just change:  `Name tempName = new Name("r");` to `Name tempName = new Name(name);` I think you wanted to do it like that

Comment: The code will not compile, it doesnt seem to recognize the getters and setters from within the class at all, very confused

Comment: Did you import the correct Name class?

Comment: "add cast to tempName" , however this doesnt fix the problem!

Comment: wat do u mean by importing correct name class? thanks

Comment: Is the `Name` class file in a different package than the class containing your `processInput` method? Did you have you use an import to use the Name class?

Comment: if you hover with your mouse pointer over the `Name` class it should  tell you the complete class name including its package, e.g. `java.lang.String`. What does it say for the `Name` of your tempName?

Comment: I just tried it and no prob to make it works here -> maybe try to change the name of your class.

Comment: I see no problem with the Name class. Put a main() method in your Name class and try calling processInput() from there. It should work. Like others have said, you may be accessing a different Name class.

Answer (score 0):

Check the imports you have in the package.
Are you importing the correct Name class?